# $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n}-\sqrt{n^2-2n}\right) $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, infinity, natural-numbers

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n}-\sqrt{n^2-2n}\right)
\end{equation}

I have tried this

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\sqrt[3]{(n+1)^3-3n-1}-\sqrt{(n-1)^2-1}\right)
\end{equation}

which leads me back to undefined $0\cdot\infty$

Comment: **Hint** write $\sqrt[3]{n^3 + 3n} = n \sqrt[3]{1 + 3n^{-2}}$ and similarly for the second term. And then use the Taylor expansion of the cube root and square root functions centered at 1.

Comment: We have not yet reached Taylor expansions. :(

Comment: And now that you have had first hand experience you should [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960); you may also want to browse through the other points raised in that FAQ about how to best set up your question so that you can get the help that you need.

Comment: **Hint 2** Rationalize the numerator. (Use the fact that for positive integers $p$ you can factor $(a^p - b^p) = (a-b) \cdot (\ldots)$.)

Comment: Perhaps this could help. Maybe you could rationalize the problem into $\frac{(n^3-3n)^{2/3}-n^2-2n}{(n^3+3n)^{1/3}+(n^2-2n)^{1/2}}$ and factor out an “n” from each radical. Then cancel the “n” out and use l’Hopital’s rule on the numerator and denominator:$\frac{\frac{d^2}{dn^2}(n^2(1-3n^{-2})^{2/3}-n-2)}{\frac{d^2}{dn^2}((1+3n^{-2})^{1/3}+(1-2n^-1)^{1/2})}$. This may not work though, but it could give insights. Please correct any errors here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n}-\sqrt{n^2-2n}= \sqrt[6]{(n^3+3n)^2}- \sqrt[6]{(n^2-2n)^3}=a^{1/6}-b^{1/6}$, where $a=(n^3+3n)^2, b=(n^2-2n)^3$ 
Let's first simplify $a^{1/6}-b^{1/6}$. Note that $a^{1/6}-b^{1/6}=\frac{a^{1/3}-b^{1/3}}{a^{1/6}+b^{1/6}}=\frac{(a^{1/3})^3-(b^{1/3})^3}{(a^{1/6}+b^{1/6})(a^{2/3}+a^{1/3}b^{1/3}+b^{2/3})}=\frac{a-b}{(a^{1/6}+b^{1/6})(a^{2/3}+a^{1/3}b^{1/3}+b^{2/3})}$

Numerator is $a-b=n^6\left ((1+\frac 3{n^2})^2-(1-\frac 2n)^3\right)=n^6(6/n+ 9/n^4+8/n^3-18/n^2)$

$1$st factor in Denominator  =$n\left((1+\frac 3n)^{1/3}+(1-\frac 2n)^{1/2}\right)$ 
$2$nd factor in Denominator=$n^4\left ( (1+\frac 3{n^2})^{4/3}+(1+\frac 3{n^2})^{2/3}(1-\frac 2n)+(1-\frac 2n)^{1/2}\right)$

So we have  
$\begin{align}\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n}-\sqrt{n^2-2n}&= \sqrt[6]{(n^3+3n)^2}- \sqrt[6]{(n^2-2n)^3}\\&=a^{1/6}-b^{1/6}\\&=\frac{6+\frac 1{n^3}(9+8n-18n^2)}{\left((1+\frac 3n)^{1/3}+(1-\frac 2n)^{1/2}\right)\left ( (1+\frac 3{n^2})^{4/3}+(1+\frac 3{n^2})^{2/3}(1-\frac 2n)+(1-\frac 2n)^{1/2}\right)}\\& \to\frac {6} {2\times 3}=1\end {align}$

Comment: This is what I got to, but isn't the answer $\infty$ incorrect, shouldn't the answer be 2?

Comment: @Milan: $\infty$ is not correct. I'm revising it. There was a mistake in my typing! Please wait.

Comment: @Milan: I have revised my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n}-\sqrt{n^2-2n} =\\= \frac{(\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n})^6-(\sqrt{n^2-2n})^6}{\big(\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n}+\sqrt{n^2-2n}\big)\cdot \big((\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n})^4+(\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n})^2\cdot(\sqrt{n^2-2n})^2+(\sqrt{n^2-2n})^4\big)}$$

**Addition.**
$$\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n}-\sqrt{n^2-2n} =\frac{(\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n})^2-(\sqrt{n^2-2n})^2}{\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n}+\sqrt{n^2-2n}}\ (1)$$

$$(\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n})^2-(\sqrt{n^2-2n})^2 =\\= \frac{(\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n})^6-(\sqrt{n^2-2n})^6}{(\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n})^4+(\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n})^2\cdot(\sqrt{n^2-2n})^2+(\sqrt{n^2-2n})^4}\ (2)$$

denominator of $(1)$ gives
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n}+\sqrt{n^2-2n}} \sim \frac{1}{2n}$$
denominator of $(2)$ gives
$$\frac{1}{(\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n})^4+(\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n})^2\cdot(\sqrt{n^2-2n})^2+(\sqrt{n^2-2n})^4} \sim \frac{1}{3n^4}$$
numerator of $(2)$ have maximum power in member $3n^4\cdot 2n$, which leads to correct result.

Comment: @Milan: I think this answers your question. Mine was still incomplete so I have deleted that for now.

Comment: Thank you all :)

Comment: Zkutch, I think your denominator is not correct. shouldn't there be terms like $a^4$ (instead of $a^2$) where $a=$ cube root of $(n^3+3n)$?

Comment: @Koro. Thanks, you are right. Fixed.

Comment: Does this really lead to a correct result? It leads me to $\frac{-6n^4+6n^5+9n^2+8n^3}{...}$, where the denominator is huge. + I think in your hint in the last term $\left(\sqrt{n^2-2n}\right)^4$ should be only to the power of 2.

Comment: Can you explain the algebra? Did you multiply with $\frac{(\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n})^6+(\sqrt{n^2-2n})^6}{(\sqrt[3]{n^3+3n})^6+(\sqrt{n^2-2n})^6}$?

Comment: @Milan. Wrote addition as promised. choosing favorite answer is your prerogative, but, as I wrote above, everything in my answer was correct from the very beginning, taking into account the first note from Koro, which was fixed when you had chosen my answer.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{gather*}
\left( n^{3} +3n\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} =n\left( 1+\frac{3}{n^{2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\\
\left( n^{2} -2n\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} =n\left( 1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
\therefore \left( n^{3} +3n\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} -\left( n^{2} -2n\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} =n\left(\left( 1+\frac{3}{n^{2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} -\left( 1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)
\end{gather*}
Recall that
\begin{gather*}
( 1+x)^{n} =1+nx+\frac{n( n-1)}{2!} x^{2} +..\\
\Longrightarrow \left( 1+\frac{3}{n^{2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} =1+\frac{1}{3} \cdotp \frac{3}{n^{2}} +\frac{1}{3} \cdotp \frac{-2}{3} \cdotp \frac{9}{2n^{4}} +..\\
=1+\frac{1}{n^{2}} -\frac{1}{n^{4}} +( other\ higher\ order\ terms)\\
\Longrightarrow \left( 1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} =1+\frac{1}{2} \cdotp \frac{-2}{n} +\frac{1}{2} \cdotp \frac{-1}{2} \cdotp \frac{4}{2n^{2}} +...\\
=1-\frac{1}{n} -\frac{1}{n^{2}} +( other\ higher\ order\ terms)
\end{gather*}
Hence,
\begin{gather*}
\Longrightarrow \left( 1+\frac{3}{n^{2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} -\left( 1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} =\frac{1}{n} +\frac{2}{n^{2}} +( other\ terms)\\
\Longrightarrow n\left(\left( 1+\frac{3}{n^{2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} -\left( 1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) =1+\frac{2}{n} +( other\ terms)\\
\Longrightarrow \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty } n\left(\left( 1+\frac{3}{n^{2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} -\left( 1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right) =1
\end{gather*}
Can you prove why the limit of the "other terms" would be zero?